# Could not find kotlin-gradle-plugin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having trouble with this android project that cannot resolve. First I tried changing jCenter() to maveCentral(), however that still doesn't work.

Here is the error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project .
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30-release-412.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.30-release-412/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.30-release-412.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.30-release-412/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.30-release-412.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Here is the gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.30-release-412"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta03"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked at [Maven Repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/), seems `1.5.30-release-412` is not exist there, maybe you can consider to use other version, `1.5.30` perhaps

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.30"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta03"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```